# I'm having problem with numbers with comma decimal separators

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have a script to calculate the water that a shower column can save, but it doesn't work properly in Firefox and Edge when I change the `,` to `.` in the values and the inverse, respectively.

I already tried using `replace`, `parsefloat`, both...

I expect that the output is the same even when using `,` and `.` in the inputs.

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return parseFloat(x.replace(",", ".").toString());
};

$('input').change(function() { // corre sempre que o valor muda
  var nrDuches = Number($('#duches').val()); // var para obter o value
  var tempEsp = Number($('#tempo').val()); //
  var prAgua = Number($('#agua').val());
  var prEnerg = Number($("#energia").val());

  $('#despesas2').html((((tempEsp * nrDuches * 365 * (prAgua / 1000)) + (tempEsp * 4.186 * 40 * 0.000278 * nrDuches * 365 * prEnerg))).toFixed(2)); // formula matemática para o output
  $('#copos').html(numberWithCommas(((tempEsp * nrDuches * 365)).toFixed())); // formula matemática para o output do nr de copo
  $('#energia2').html(numberWithCommas(((tempEsp * 4.186 * 40 * 0.000278 * nrDuches * 365)).toFixed())); // formula matemática para o output do numero de dias de aquecimento
});
```

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/rafaeltpires/t3a2kLnx/7/

Comment: Do you mean the calculation fails when someone uses a `,` as a decimal separator in the input fields?

Comment: yes, exacly that!

Comment: You only call `numberWithCommas` *after* you've done all the mathematical operations with the number that (potentially) has a comma in it. You have to do it beforehand. EDIT: actually, since the first thing you do after fetching the input is to pass it through `Number`, you will already have `NaN` from the beginning.

Comment: You have no need to `numberWithCommas()` function this will call every single time when user enter the value. so just user `replace()`. i posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you only call your `numberWithCommas()` function *after* you have retrieved the values with comma as a decimal separator and tried to perform the calculations with it. You need to do this *first*, right at the point you read the values from the `input` controls. Try this:

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return parseFloat(x.replace(",", ".").toString());
};

$('input').change(function() { // corre sempre que o valor muda
  var nrDuches = Number(numberWithCommas($('#duches').val()));
  var tempEsp = Number(numberWithCommas($('#tempo').val()));
  var prAgua = Number(numberWithCommas($('#agua').val()));
  var prEnerg = Number(numberWithCommas($("#energia").val()));

  $('#despesas2').html(((tempEsp * nrDuches * 365 * (prAgua / 1000)) + (tempEsp * 4.186 * 40 * 0.000278 * nrDuches * 365 * prEnerg)).toFixed(2));
  $('#copos').html((tempEsp * nrDuches * 365).toFixed());
  $('#energia2').html((tempEsp * 4.186 * 40 * 0.000278 * nrDuches * 365).toFixed());
});
```

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.caixa {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 6px 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  background: transparent;
}

.reduzido {
  width: 90px;
}

.reduzir {
  width: 75px;
}

.reduzir2 {
  width: 75px;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableCell,
.divTable.blueTable .divTableHead {
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

.blueTable .tableFootStyle .links {
  text-align: left;
}

.blueTable .tableFootStyle .links a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.blueTable.outerTableFooter {
  border-top: none;
}

.blueTable.outerTableFooter .tableFootStyle {
  padding: 15px 15px;
}


/* RESPONSIVE CSS 992PX */

.mobilecalculadora {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -12%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .divTable.blueTable .divTableCell,
  .divTable.blueTable .divTableHead {
    padding: 15px 15px;
  }
  .blueTable .tableFootStyle {}
  .blueTable .tableFootStyle .links {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .blueTable .tableFootStyle .links a {
    padding: 20px 20px;
  }
  .blueTable.outerTableFooter {
    border-top: none;
  }
  .blueTable.outerTableFooter .tableFootStyle {
    padding: 15px 15px;
  }
  /* DivTable.com */
  .divTable {
    display: block;
  }
  .divTableRow {
    display: block;
  }
  .divTableHeading {
    display: block;
  }
  .divTableCell,
  .divTableHead {
    display: block;
  }
  .divTableHeading {
    display: block;
  }
  .divTableFoot {
    display: block;
  }
  .divTableBody {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .mobilecalculadora {
    font-size: 50% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divTable blueTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <div style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><label>Quantidade água fria até chegar água quente*:</label></span>
          <span style="color: #ffffff;"><input id="tempo" class="caixa reduzir2" name="tempo" required="" type="text" value="7.5" placeholder="Tempo de Espera" /></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="divTableCell" style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><label>Duches diários:</label></span>
          <span style="color: #ffffff;"><input id="duches" class="caixa reduzir" maxlength="2" name="duches" size="2" type="text" value="2" /></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell" style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><label>Custo energia:[€/kWh(th)]</label></span>
          <span style="color: #ffffff;"><input id="energia" class="caixa reduzir2" name="energia" required="" type="text" value="0.2" placeholder="Custo de Energia" /></span></div>
        <div class="divTableCell" style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><label>Custo água:[€/m3]</label></span>
          <span style="color: #ffffff;"><input id="agua" class="caixa reduzir2" name="agua" required="" type="text" value="4.5" placeholder="Custo água na sua zona" /></span></div>
        <div class="divTableCell" style="text-align: left;">
          <div class="mobilecalculadora">
            <h3 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 36pt;">Poupança Anual: <strong><span id="despesas2" class=""> 75.61</span>€</strong>
              </span>
            </h3>
            <h4 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 18pt;">Quantidade de água desperdiçada num ano <strong><span id="copos" class="">5475</span> </strong>Litros </span>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell" style="text-align: left;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace Your `Variables` as under No need of `function numberwithCommas()`

```
  var nrDuches = Number($('#duches').val().replace(',','.').toString());//
  var tempEsp = Number($('#tempo').val().replace(',','.').toString()); //
  var prAgua = Number($('#agua').val().replace(',','.').toString());
  var prEnerg = Number($("#energia").val().replace(',','.').toString());
```